# Use of undeclared identifier 'RNFirebaseNotifications' 'RNFirebaseMessaging'

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, facebook, testflight

fb login SDKs it was working fine but now starting giving these errors.

My imports are like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <RNFirebaseNotifications.h>
#import <RNFirebaseMessaging.h>
```

Kindly help to resolve it. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3008

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exact issue today. To fix it, move your `#import` statements outside of the `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` block.

Comment: In my case i was using wrong provisioning profile to build app.

Comment: Your code above has the import statements in the wrong place though, and the build would fail when sonarkit is disabled.